# New rule for halal-haram questions

Tags: discussion

I propose a new rule for questions that are tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram): If you are asking if something is forbidden (or permissible), you have to indicate some reason for why you think that may or may not be the case. We know that in all things other than worship, the principle is "permissible unless indicated otherwise." If you have a reason to suspect that something is indicated impermissible, write down that reason.

This is not a binary thing - the more substantive material you have to suspect the permissibility or impermissibility of something, the stronger your question. For example, something from the texts is great. If not, something from a scholar. A widespread belief in some area may also fly. But "I heard from someone" is most likely not going to cut it.

Comment: Cross-ref: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1486/214

Comment: What if it's from a strong unverifiable, unwritten source (like a khatib during Friday prayers)? Sometimes these things grow into a cultural acceptance that it is haraam, but nobody ever finds any source other than 'a religious authority'. Blogs are often the only written indicators of such things. Would blogs suffice as a good enough source?

Answer (score 4):

I made a comment on https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5971/156 along the same lines:

> This question could be improved by clarifying it. Namely: **Why do you ask?** We could flood the site with questions about whether this song or that song, or some poem, or anything else, was Kufr. **Explain why you have a query in this instance. What is it about this specific song which makes you doubtful?** Why do you think it *might* be Kufr? And you do you think it *might not* be? Answer those two questions (briefly), and you have a much more valuable question here.

Basically, questions without that clarification are too open-ended to be useful, and often give the answerers nothing to go on. They are **not constructive** questions.

Comment: +1 Exactly my point.