# Should question 17942 be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> - [Is it Haram or Makruh to use the phone of our office (if the boss doesn't allow it) to talk with our family? (the view of Sunni scholars)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17942/is-it-permissible-to-use-the-phone-of-our-office-which-is-not-personal-in-orde)

In my view, the above question is quite pointless, as well as the answer can vary. As well as the question is so simple that common sense can answer it (ask the boss of your office), and assuming that any scholar would have or has ever answered such a question or a similar one, it would mean the question shows very low research effort.

I believe it should be closed, but not sure as what. Should it be closed as Unclear, too broad, or as off-topic? or is it possible for the question to be salvaged?

Similar questions (the problems I see in them can be covered by what I said above):

- [Is it Haram or Makruh to use the office's phone (without the permission of the boss) to talk with our family? (Shia view)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/is-that-halal-to-use-the-phone-of-the-office-which-is-not-personal-in-order-to)
- [According to Shia Islam, is it permissible to speak by mobile phone during the time of working?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/according-to-shia-islam-is-it-permissible-to-speak-by-mobile-phone-during-the-t)
- [It is Haram to use your cellphone at your office during your work time? (Sunni View)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17940/it-is-haram-to-use-your-cellphone-at-your-office-during-your-work-time-sunni-v)

Comment: I edited my questions somewhat, I assume this is better than before. Of course I edtted your question in meta somewhat (with your permission please). Actually I removed some of the points which you mentioned as the problems...  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Initially, as I mentioned in the comment, I edited my question.

Secondly, I reckon my edited question is not unclear, Since it has mentioned "is it a Haram deed or Makruh (according to Sunni)

Thirdly you termed those 3 questions as similar questions, I ought to say that:

The initial question asked for the view of Shia (not Sunni), So as far as I know, these kinds of questions which are inquired separately ( not inquire for both Shia and Sunni view), are in accordance with the policy of this site.

That's why occasionally I strive to inquire questions in two separated views of Shia and Sunni (although I myself believe that we ought to let the users to see the viewpoints of Shia and Sunni in the same question, then they can decide..

Actually I assume we ought to be optimist regarding this issue, not to be pessimist and don’t think that each question (which inquires both Sunni and Shia views) will lead to …

But regarding the second and third questions which you mentioned them as the similar question, I shall say that:

Those are two quite different questions, Since I have inquired regarding "if it is permissible or Haram to use our mobile phone during our work time, Since as you know, as a rule, it is a law that a clerk should solely work on his job time (do the jobs which are related to the office jobs, not wasting the time to talk with different individuals by the cell phone, but my another question asked if it is Haram to use the phone of the offices which is not a personal device…

I reckon it made you confused, because there have been used some similar words in those questions, that's why you thought they are similar...

Comment: They are basically the same, they all center around a job and a phone and permissibility.  The questions really show low research effort, and I would lean more to classifying them as too broad rather then unclear.

Comment: But what does it have to do with Islam?

Answer (score 1):

As phrased, it really doesn't make any sense.  As best I can tell, it's asking whether you're allowed to use the phone for personal calls when your boss tells you you're not allowed to use the phone for personal calls.

It opens with an understanding that he's not allowed to use the phone to make personal calls in this case, but there is absolutely [nothing in the question to suggest](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663/22) that there should ever be any Islamic reason for that *not* to be case.

The meat of the question just seems to be whether it's considered out-and-out forbidden (*haram*) or reprehensible (*makruh*) by "Sunnis," but with absolutely no attempt to tie it to a particular scholar or even jurisprudent model.

All-in-all, it's sloppily written, shows zero actual research effort and — especially when taken with the other three questions — just looks to be an attempt at fatwa shopping rather than an actual focussed question.