# Are questions about a specific company's goods or services on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

Are questions of type "Is X product/service of Y company halal?, "Is Z company halal?" allowed here ([example](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26100/))?

Or if they should be flagged, what's the appropriate flag to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrinsically, I don't see that they should be off-topic here (presuming of course that they don't cross the line into [spam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)). Ideally it could be generalized such that it applies to more than exactly one business, but not everything needs to (or even *can*) fit into that perfect sphere of maximal general usefulness.

However, questions such as those you linked are problematic for another reason: There's a significant dearth of details. Basically, what it's doing is asking someone to go through *every single aspect of Z company's business model* and give a definitive ruling that it *as a whole* is "halal/haram".

Should this question then be closed as too broad? I don't know; I'm neither an expert in formulating such fatawa nor have I perused the details of the business to know the depth of research required to even *begin* to formulate such a fatwa.

As a general rule-of-thumb, questions asking whether something is (or is not) haram should at least have a [reasonable cause to believe that it's something that *could* be haram in the first place](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663/22). As written, it neither indicates what exactly aspect of the business would potentially *be* haram in the first place, nor why the previously-read article on MLM schemes wouldn't (shouldn't?) apply. This, to me, is a more-than-attainable bar for research effort on any such question, and if included would at least give potential answerers something to work with.

As such, I would recommend downvoting the question, as it "does not show any research effort". Whether it deserves more than that, I'd defer to an actual expert in the field.

But no, I wouldn't consider it off-topic at all.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!