# How do we answer a question "Is X haram?" when there's no reason to think X is haram?

Tags: discussion, questions

Here's some unanswered questions of the form "Is X haram?" where there's no given reason (nor obvious reason) to think that X would be haram.

1. [Is sale of luxurious goods with a huge profit margin haraam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28814/17163)
2. [Naming a company after one of the (99) names of Allah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31469/17163)
3. [Is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry a Christian woman who has a non-religious tattoo? (Sunni viewpoint)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35484/17163)
4. [Is creating a chat app or application haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35928/17163)
5. [Is it permissible for a husband to seek another spouse during a breakdown in his marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37027/17163)
6. [Can a couple consummate their marriage outside the home?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38512/17163)
7. [Are Muslims allowed to research/read/listen about sex related content (not porn)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39362/17163)
8. [Can the translated Quran and the Arabic Quran be read in a clean place outside?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45462/17163)

In each of these unanswered questions, there's a comment to the effect of "why would it be haram?"  E.g.

> Why would you think it's haraam in the first place? The general rule in *fiqh* is that everything is permissible unless proven otherwise. – [goldPseudo ♦](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28814/is-sale-of-luxurious-goods-with-a-huge-profit-margin-haraam#comment49116_28814)

This basically answers all these questions.

**Question**: How do we answer a question "Is X haram?" when there's no reason to think X is haram?

This is related to this question: [Do we need to check whether things are haram when they probably aren't?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36200/17163)  The current answer to this question writes:

> Therefore in similar cases I'm trying to ask the poster what makes him think such and such is haram, because one needs to analyze the reasoning to be able to correct these false thoughts hoping this would help him/her in the future.
>   <sub>[Medi1Saif ♦](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/36211/17163)</sub>

---

*Observations*:

In [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36200/17163) I list 7 questions, and from these:

1. two have now been automatically deleted: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35983/17163), [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30963/17163);
2. two (maybe three) have top answers say that essentially we should "apply the default ruling": [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35455/17163), [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30650/17163), and maybe [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35733/17163);
3. one was unanswered for two years: [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30516/17163); and
4. the accepted answer to [Freelancing Haram or Halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16163/17163) begins with *FreeLancing is obviously not haram.*

[G. Bach's question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838/17163) lists four such questions, and from these:

1. one has an answer that's effectively "apply the default ruling": [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9449/17163);
2. the other three have answers with no references, so they're the opinions of people on the Internet: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36836/17163), [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36529/17163), [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36790/17163).

Of the eight questions listed above, six did not receive an answer after 1+ years, one after 11 months ([1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39362/17163)) and one after 2 months ([2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45462/17163)).

I feel safe to declare that these 7+4+8=19 questions did not attract meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Why do you think X would be haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663/22)" is pretty much *the most basic* research effort required for this class of question. If they're lacking even that, you should mostly just be closing them as dupes of "[Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838/22)" or downvoting them into oblivion. Probably both.

"I heard/thought a thing, is it true?" type questions, which many of these are, are decidedly low-quality. Even the simplest ones require *far* more effort on the part of the answerer than on the questioner, and it's way too easy for these sorts of [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) to overwhelm the site and just bog everything down. Wasting your time (or your experts' time) on these when the questioner couldn't be bothered to put in any effort of their own is just a losing game which pretty much *only* ends with everyone getting bored and leaving.

Comment: The downside of closing as a duplicate is that these questions won't be auto-deleted.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones That's not necessarily a downside, insofar as it would still be acting as a signpost to an *actually good* question for future visitors.

Comment: Something boring for you may not be boring for everyone else.

Comment: These question are not getting answers; they just sit there for years unanswered.  If they're actually interesting, they'll likely be asked again (and hopefully asked properly the next time).

Answer (score 3):

I might use a comment template to vote to close (overwriting the auto-generated one):

> `We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.`

This displays as:

> We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Closing as a duplicate of [Is X halal? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838)

Extended version:

> `We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)`

This displays as:

> We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)